# How to get HOG descriptor to use any other classifier than Svm

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have been working on a code to detect people in a video but cannot find any way to make hog work with any other classifier than LinearSvmClassifier.
For more i info what i want is to use RandomForestClassifier instead of svm to check if it improves its accuracy in detection. Link to code [here.](https://github.com/Vishu-Chaudhary/ImageProcessingProjects/blob/master/detect.py)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')
ret,frame = vid.read()

while ret:
    ret,frame = vid.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame,width = min(400, frame.shape[1]))
    orignal = frame.copy()

    # DETECTING PEOPLE
    (rects,weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(frame,winStride = (4, 4), padding = (8, 8), scale = .05)
    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(orignal, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Now applying non maxima supression with fairely large threshhold to 
    # maintain overlapping that are still people
    rects = np.array([[x, y, x+w, y+h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
    pick  = non_max_suppression(rects, probs = None, overlapThresh = 0.65)

    # Drawing final boundary boxes
    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0,255,0), 2)

    print("[INFO] {} orignal boxes, {} after supression".format(len(rects), len(pick)))

    # show Output
    cv2.imshow("Before NMS", orignal)
    cv2.imshow("After NMS", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: did you google and find for example this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595328/opencv-3-0-hogdescriptorcompute-code-example

Comment: well the point is i want to use any other classifier than LinearSvm.I did google for it but couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: typically classification uses some number of features and trains/computes the classification from it. So I thought your question was about how to compute the features and/or what are the features in HoG? For HoG the features are the bins of the histogram of oriented gradients descriptor, so I thought the question was about how to compute the HoG descriptor (instead of calling the .detect or .detectMultiscale method which uses svm only).

Comment: what i can't understand is why `hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())` this .I know this svm is trained to detect full body but the problem is its not accurate for a camera viewpoint at greater height

Comment: just ignore that. The whole class is made for detection by SVM classification, but as far as I know, you can still compute and use the raw HoG descriptor (without setting any svm detector).

Comment: how to do that .Well using Hog in sklearn to extractFratures could be used but no idea at all.

Comment: just setup your HoG descriptor parameters (except .setSVMDetector) and then use hog.compute (as it is done in the link in my first comment) instead of hog.detectMultiscale on the training samples (with some fixed training sample resolution) and use the results in a classification training method that you prefer that uses floating point features.

Comment: So what basically i will be doing is creating a training model first and then for my test video computing the hog features and passing them to my classifier to predict on the basis of trained model. Right?